# Is it possible to have multiple DB schemas in one SQLDB service instance?

Tags: ibm-cloud

Is it possible to have multiple DB schemas in one SQLDB service instance? Can I execute commands such as CREATE DATABASE.

Comment: why the close vote? there are two perfect questions 1) multiple schemas? 2) CREATE DATABASE?

Answer (score 5):

Depends on the plan in use. With the **Free plan**, you only get one schema and every bind to an app gives you the same credentials. With the **Small** and **Premium** plans, you get a database and each bind to an app gives a different set of credentials.  For more information, see the link below:

http://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/SQLDB/index.html#sqldb_009